# Why total reputation summary is different in All Time and month?

Tags: bug, status-completed, statistics

I think Total Reputation table shown on Right on below pages should be same. But they are not. What exactly do these tables depict then?

- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow
- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow
- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow
- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow
- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow

[image: Different count in total reputation table on right side of league]

Comment: It is the same. What are you talking about?

Comment: @CodyGray OP is talking about the *Total Reputation* table at the right side of the page

Comment: @CodyGray Added image to clarify what I mean.

Comment: It is similar for other sites as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, that didn't make any sense (the actual displayed numbers were "out of all users who had any reputation change during the given timeframe, how many have a total rep of X?" -- that's not a very meaningful statistic).

The Total Reputation now shows the same data on all league pages, namely the version that was on the "all time" league page.

Comment: Thanks. And it means that I had raised a real bug(kind of). :P