# Is Total Reputation and Year Reputation calculation engine calculation misleading?

Tags: discussion, bug, statistics, reputation-leagues

I am relatively a new user on Stack Overflow. I have noticed that Year Reputation and Total Reputation (for other as well viz. quarter, month, week) calculation engine on leagues is having some problem and does not take into effect the reputation you lose. Example

> Say On Jan 1, 2013 you have a total reputation of 200. You earn 150 reputation and lose 10 reputation leading to a total change of 140 reps, but leagues does not takes -10 reps in the calculation and instead shows only 150 as your reputation change. I have not investigated this in detail, but from my profile itself it is evident.

Month -> *Prev Reputation* + Reputation Gain = Calculated Rep -> **Real Reputation**

[Feb 2014](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2014-02-01/2711647?sort=reputationchange#2711647) -> ... + 133 = ... -> **136**

[Mar 2014](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2014-03-01/2711647?sort=reputationchange#2711647) -> *136* + 302 = 438 -> **428** (See the difference)

[Apr 2014](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2014-04-01/2711647?sort=reputationchange#2711647) -> *428* + 023 = 451 -> **451**

[May 2014](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2014-05-01/2711647?sort=reputationchange#2711647) -> *451* + 100 = 551 -> **551**

Please let me know if I am wrong somewhere, I have earlier noticed similar difference in [All time and Month Total Reputation summary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256417/2711647)

Comment: This is by design, actually.

Comment: Not calculating negative reputation changes by design?

Comment: See [Why is my total reputation less than my monthly reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141628)